# Redeclaration error with same classname in different Source Sets

Tags: android, gradle

Similar to flavor variants, I was expecting the ability to have source set variants for the same classname. For example,

*androidTest* directory

```
class RobotTest(val name: String = "androidTest")
```

*main* directory

```
class RobotTest(val name: String = "main")
```

*test* directory

```
class RobotTest(val name: String = "test")
```

Android Studio is okay when I have the same classname in just 2 of the sources:

- `main` and `test`
- `main` and `androidTest`

However, once I add the same class to all three, Android Studio shows an Analysis error in `test` and `androidTest` with the message:

> Redeclaration: RobotTest

I ran the code in a unit test, instrumented test, and in the app and everything compiled fine (no build errors) and when logging `RobotTest().name`, I correctly get the 3 different values for each class context.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this or if this isn't allowed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you have created a product flavor you should not place your varianted class into `main` source set.

Keep **only common** for all variants files into `main`

For example, you defined:

```
  flavorDimensions("api")
  productFlavors {
      create("real") {
          dimension = "api"
      }
      create("mock") {
          dimension = "api"
      }
  }
```

Since that, you have exactly TWO build variants: `real` OR `mock`.

So, you have to have exactly TWO versions of your class (if it should be different):

```
/src/real/kotlin/com/example/SomeApi.kt
/src/main/kotlin/com/example/ (no file here)
/src/mock/kotlin/com/example/SomeApi.kt
```

UPD:

All above is correct ***only for sources***! If you create 4 flavors, you **must** copy your Java/Kotlin class into 4 folders, you don't have a 'default' one.

For ***resources***, the logic is different.
Gradle, at first, takes the resource file (some XML file) from the default folder 'main' and then replaces it with the overridden one from the flavor folder if the file exists there. If you create 4 flavors, you **can keep a default** in 'main' and you **can** override it only once.

Comment: Hmm, I thought you'd always add it to main so you'd have a default class when creating other flavors. I will give this a try though and check back. Thanks

Comment: What if I have 5 product flavors, and I only need to modify 1 product flavor value? Are you suggesting I duplicate the class in all flavors even though 4 will be redundant? @Nistix

Comment: @blinkmacalahan Unfortunately, yes, you have to keep redundant copies, or I have no idea how to handle it :( I have updated my answer. This weird behavior is applied only for source files, not for resources. The resource files can have a 'default' variant.

Comment: sorry for the late acceptance. You're 100% correct. It is confusing that for resources it is one way but for code is is another.